# How to get descendants of a panel in teststack.white

Tags: ui-automation, white-framework

I need some elements that are the childs of some 3-4 panels, but in those panels I can identify only the 1st parent panel and rest don't have any identifiers, so please help me to find the descendants of the 1st parent panel.

let's say - Parent#1 only can be identified as "workspace" but the immediate child panels are not detectable (Edit#1/ Edit#2 and button under unknown panels are identified), so i want to reach to the edit boxes, please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Use `SearchCriteria` to find the parent Panel1
2. Use the `GetElement` method in `TeskStack.White.UIItem`:

`Panel1.GetElement(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)`